# Using reflection principle to find probabilities

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, finance

[image]

[image]

I'm not able to answer these questions because firstly I don't understand the reflection principle properly. Secondly if someone could provide a visual explanation as to how this process works then that would be very helpful.

Any help would be much appreciated.